# Angular 2 checkbox - How to use [checked] with (ngModelChange)?

Tags: forms, angular

I'm having trouble programmatically setting a checkbox in Angular 2. The following code fires `onCheck()` whenever the user checks the checkbox. I can also check the checkbox programmatically by setting `this.select` to 'true'.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="v.checked" [checked]="select" (ngModelChange)="onCheck(v.checked)">
```

My problem is that when I set `this.select` to 'true', `ngModelChange` doesn't seem to detect the change and `onCheck()` doesn't fire... :-(

Any tips? Is there an alternative way to programmatically set a checkbox AND have its associated function fire?

Answer (score 0):

you can use checkbox with component variable like :

```
@Component({
  selector : 'my-component'
  template : `<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selected"/>`
})
export class MyComponent(){
   public selected: boolean = false;
}
```